# In Matplotlib what is the Polar equivalent of get_xdata?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mouseevent, polar-coordinates

I found the following example of selecting data with the mouse but when I use the onpick function with a polar plot I get the following error:

```
xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
AttributeError: 'PolarAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_xdata'
```

What is the polar method to get theta and r using the mouse?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click on points')

line, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(100), 'o', picker=5) # 5 points tolerance

def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    print 'onpick points:', zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind])

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You are using a standard plot and want to extract polar coordinates from it? This is really strange...
Usually you define first the axes instance to be a polar representation : ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar = True) and plot the points using a random angle and a random radius.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with IPython 0.13.2 and matplotlib 1.3.0, even with a polar subplot. You shouldn't include the code for the _example_ you found (a link is better for this purpose), you should **include the code used to produce the plot giving you the error**. All we can do for now is _guess_ how you have defined the `onpick` event, which is not optimal.

Comment: Also, the code you posted does not generate a polar graph, which makes me think it is not the code you are actually using.

Comment: I pared down my data set and my program to include here and it works fine! I'll just have to debug what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting your code to print a polar graphic, it worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line = plt.polar(2*np.pi*np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100),
                  'o', picker=5)[0] # 5 points tolerance
plt.gca().set_title('click on points')

def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    print 'onpick points:', zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind])

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```